# Is Iterator a collection in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections

I have a confusion about Iterator in Scala that is it a Collection or a way to access the elements of a Collection one by one? So if it's not a Collection then how we use Iterator as Iterator("a", "number", "of", "words") ?
Ref - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_iterators.htm

Comment: How do you define "collection"? Whether or not the definition of "collection" includes or excludes `Iterator` depends on your definition of "collection". Without telling us, what your definition of "collection" is, it is impossible to answer whether `Iterator` meets your definition of "collection".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how [can] we use Iterator as `Iterator("a", "number", "of", "words")` [even though it is not a Collection]?

There is nothing special about this syntax that makes it exclusive for use by `Collections`. What we have here is an `apply` method on `object Iterator` that takes a variable number of arguments (and returns an Iterator instance backed by the sequence of those arguments):

```
/** Creates an iterator with given elements.
 *
 *  @param elems  The elements returned one-by-one from the iterator
 *  @return An iterator which produces the given elements on the
 *          first calls to `next`, and which has no further elements.
 */
 def apply[A](elems: A*): Iterator[A] = elems.iterator
```

You could make the same for your own classes.

This provides for a nice syntax for "builder methods".

Answer (score 0):

Iterators are a crude form of collection, or rather an interface to one.

Looking at the apply method on the Iterator companion object we notice that it just returns `elems.iterator`:

```
/** Creates an iterator with given elements.
 *
 *  @param elems  The elements returned one-by-one from the iterator
 *  @return An iterator which produces the given elements on the
 *          first calls to `next`, and which has no further elements.
 */
 def apply[A](elems: A*): Iterator[A] = elems.iterator
```

Variable-arguments like `elems` are actually of type `mutable.WrappedArray[A]` which implements the IterableLike trait and thus provides an Iterator[A].